# If $N_1, N_2, \dots, N_n$ are distinct unique Sylow subgroups, how do we know $N_i \cap (N_1N_2 \cdots N_{i-1}N_{i+1} \cdots N_n)=\{1\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, direct-sum

If $N_1, N_2, \dots, N_n$ are distinct unique Sylow subgroups, how do we know $$N_i \cap (N_1N_2 \cdots N_{i-1}N_{i+1} \cdots N_n)=\{1\}$$

Comment: Do you mean the $N_i$'s to be normal?

Comment: Yes. Each $N_i$ is normal.

Comment: OK, then Mesels answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $\gcd\left(\left|N_i\right|,\left|N_j\right|\right)=1$ if $i\neq j$

Hence, $$\gcd\left(\left|N_i\right|,\left|\prod_{k\neq i} N_k\right|\right)=1$$

Thus, their intersection is trivial.

Comment: Why does their gcd being $\{1\}$ imply that their intersection is trivial?

Comment: @Pacman: Let $H,K$ be two groups such that $gcd(|H|,|K|)=1$. Since $H\cap K$ is both subgroup of $H$ and $K$, $|H\cap K|$ divides order of both of them. Hence it is trivial group.

Comment: How do we know $\prod_{k \ne i}N_k$ is a group?

Comment: @Pacman: product of two normal subgroups is a normal subgroup..